# Centering an image vertically and horizontally according to current window size

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I have read the other SO questions related this matter, but I could not find an answer to my issue.

I want to center an image horizontally and vertically in a `div` having width and height equal to 100%. In other words, if someone resizes the browser window, the image should remain in the center of the window, no matter it's current size.

I have tried to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B68c3/) something, but cannot make it work.

How can I make it work? Is it possible? Can someone show an operational example in JsFiddle? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the image dimensions?

Comment: Yes, in the JsFiddle, it is 32 x 32

Comment: Use this as a template? http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position fixed and don't even need a wrapper div (you can add it in though if you like):

```
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

The margins are half the image size (you mentioned it's known).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B68c3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CSS like this:

```
background:url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: Can you share an operational example in JsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the window size, you have set it to 100px instead of 100%....

Comment: @JVerstry Is the size of the `div` going to be in relation to the size of the window?